# Function $ dont work in PHP and MYSQL combination

Tags: php, mysql

i am wondering why this wont excute, i mean this excute successfull but reff is just $r but i want to be what did i wrote,

```
$r = $_GET['r'];
```

And $r is nickname like page.php?r=nickname.

```
$query_new_user_insert = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_password_hash, user_email, user_activation_hash, user_registration_ip, user_registration_datetime, reff) VALUES(:user_name, :user_password_hash, :user_email, :user_activation_hash, :user_registration_ip, now(), "$r")');
```

Can you guys try to solve this, i tryed just $r but it wont write... just like error or something.. please help, best regards.

error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':user_name, :user_password_hash, :user_email, :user_activation_hash, :user_regis' at line 1`

Comment: so... you have a nice query with placeholders and everything, and then you go stuff in a $_GET parameter, re-opening you to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). .... **WHHHHYYYYYY?????** As for why it's not working, learn basic PHP string syntax: https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Comment: You are using a single quote in your statement which does not allow for resolution of variables. single quote string statements and double quote are not inter-changable.

Comment: how about you provide us with the error you are getting instead of just saying that it errors or something.

Comment: There's no error, it just wont wrote to database, i will try again, and i dont know how to bind this one... if you can help, please... and Marc, what are you talking about sir? xD tnx all

Comment: Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':user_name, :user_password_hash, :user_email, :user_activation_hash, :user_regis' at line 1

Comment: My guess is; you're using `mysqli_` to connect with or `mysql_`. It explains the syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':user_name

- Notice the quote => `':user_name`? MySQL is talking to you.

Going out on a limb here, but I'm pretty sure that's what the problem is.

Your DB connection is most likely `mysqli_` or `mysql_` and you're using PDO syntax to query with. ***I've seen this type of error before.***

Those different MySQL APIs do not intermix with each other, which explains the syntax error.

- I've seen your other question: [mysql_query wont execute from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29829158/)

You're using `mysql_` in there.

- Read up on [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
- Read up on [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)
- Consult also: PHP: Choosing an API - Manual https://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing

Again, different MySQL APIs do **not** intermix with each other.
**Use a single API from connection to query.**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is variable substitution. When using double quotes around a string, variables will be replaced with their value. If you are using single quotes, they aren't. You end up with the literal string `$variableName`, not the value in that variable.

To fix, you need to either use double quotes around your query or concatenate the variable into the string.

```
$someVar = "test";
echo "This variable will show it's value: $someVar";
//This variable will show it's value: test

echo 'This variable will show it\'s name: $someVar";
//This variable will show it's value: $someVar

echo 'This variable is concatenated and will show it\'s value: '.$someVar;
//This variable is concatenated and will show it's value: test
```

This is in addition to the fact that you are open to sql injection. You really should bind your query with a parameter like every other value on there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
$stmt = $this->db_connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_password_hash, user_email, user_activation_hash, user_registration_ip, user_registration_datetime, reff) VALUES(:user_name, :user_password_hash, :user_email, :user_activation_hash, :user_registration_ip, now(), :r))");

$stmt->bindParam(':user_name', $name);
//bind other params
..........................
$stmt->bindParam(':r', $r);

$name = 'one';
// other values
..........................
$r = $_GET['r'];
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: It looks good but i got error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':user_name, :user_password_hash, :user_email, :user_activation_hash, :user_regis' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want. And read the links in marc's comment, they're important.

```
$query_new_user_insert = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO users (
    user_name, 
    user_password_hash, 
    user_email, 
    user_activation_hash, 
    user_registration_ip, 
    user_registration_datetime, 
    reff) 
VALUES(
    :user_name, 
    :user_password_hash, 
    :user_email, 
    :user_activation_hash, 
    :user_registration_ip, 
    :user_registration_datetime,
    :reff)');

$query_new_user_insert->execute(array(
    ':user_name' => $user_name,
    ':user_password_hash' => $user_password_hash,
    ':user_email' => $user_email,
    ':user_activation_hash' => $user_activation_hash,
    ':user_registration_ip' => $user_registration_ip,
    ':user_registration_datetime' => now(),
    ':reff' => $_GET['r']
    ));
$results = $query_new_user_insert->fetchAll();
```